# Does Liquid have a "does not contain" or "not in array" operator?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

When calling items from an array in a Liquid template, how do you call `does not contain` or `not in array`?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`unless` to the rescue !

Create an [A, B, C] array.

```
{% assign input = "A,B,C" | split:"," %}
```

`unless` print only if constrain is not met.

This prints nothing:

```
{% unless input contains 'A' %}No A{% endunless %}
```

This prints "**No Z**":

```
{% unless input contains 'Z' %}No Z{% endunless %}
```

Comment: My problem is I can't do something like this: `{% if input contains 'A' and input does not contain 'Z' %}`

Comment: Use two nested conditions `{% if input contains 'A' %}{% unless input contain 'Z' %}`

Answer (score 17):

you could do something like this:

```
{% if collection.tags contains 'tag' %}
{% else %}
  do stuff!
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to loop throw product variants in collection / search result page and display current variant format, so in `product-grid-item.liquid` file. In our webshop some formats have two version of colors, so I had to make to show formats only one.

I tried Lucas answer too, but it didn't work, don't understand, why.

So I solved another way: declared a string before loop and set it's value to the current variant format. Than check if next variant format is not the previously value.

```
{% assign currentFormat = '' %}
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}
    {%- if currentFormat != variant.title -%}
        <div>{{ variant_title }}</div>
        {% assign currentFormat = variant.title %}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```