# How to select specific items in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Assuming I have a list of tags: `iFix_6.3`, `iFix_7.0`, `iFix_7.1`, `iFix_8.0`, `announcement`, and so on... and I want to run an operation only on certain *several* tags. How can I check for these multiple values?

There is `contains`, but I'm looking for the opposite of it and for multiple values...

Here is an example where I actually filter out all posts that contain the `iFix_6.3` tag, thus display all other posts. This actually does not work yet... plus needs to be extended to work for multiple tags.

```
// posts with iFix_xxx tag should be filtered from the main posts view.
{% assign postUpdates = site.posts | where_exp:"item", "item.tags != 'iFix_6.3'" %} 
{% for post in postUpdates limit:10 %}
<div class="postItem inline">
    <p class="postDate">{% if post.pinned %}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>{% endif %}{{post.date | date: '%B %d, %Y'}}</p>
    <p class="postTitle"><a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How about looping through all posts and filtering with an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by building an array of excluded tags (`excluded_tags`) using `split` and a string of the comma-separated tags. Then for each post, you iterate on the post's tags. Check if the tag is in `excluded_tags` using `contains`, if it is then raise the flag `filtered_out` to not display the post, using the `unless` control flow tag.

```
{% assign excluded_tags = "iFix_6.2,iFix_6.3,announcement" | split : "," %}

{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %}
   {% assign filtered_out = False %}
   {% for tag in post.tags %}
       {% if excluded_tags contains tag %}
           {% assign filtered_out = True %}
           {% break %}
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}

   {% unless filtered_out %}
       ...
   {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe something else is interfering here, because the blog posts that should be excluded still appear in the list. What is a way to debug what gets filtered and what doesn't?

Comment: Print out what's going on in the `{% for tag in post.tags %}` loop to debug.

Comment: Sorry for the n00bism, but, how do I do that?

Comment: {{tag}}, {{excluded_tags}}, {{filtered_out}}, etc

Answer (score 0):

Seems [`unless`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823063/4058484) would solve the case.

```
{% assign postUpdates = site.posts | where_exp:"item", "unless item.tags contains 'iFix_6.3'" %}
```