# How do I create an array from a forloop?

Tags: arrays, jekyll, liquid

I have a folder of images that I'd like to render on a page. I'd like these images to be ordered/filtered a particular way. To do that, I understand that the images need to first be together in an array.

I therefore start with an empty array:

```
{% assign my_array = "" %}
```

I then loop through the image folder, and attempt different ways of **pushing each image into** `my_array`. Example:

```
{% for image in site.static_files %}
  {% if image.path contains "assets/images/target-folder" %}
     <!-- Push image into array -->
     {{ my_array | push: image }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally, I can then use this array as intended:

```
{% for image in my_array | sort:"date" | reverse %}
  <!-- show image -->
{% endfor %}
```

I'm aware that I could make a data file with the images, but I'd like to avoid needing to take that extra step. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are almost there, the way of how you are creating the array it is the only thing to fix.

This `{% assign my_array = "" %}` creates an empty string. One easy way to create an array in Liquid is to split the above:

```
{% assign my_array = "" | split: ',' %}
```

Now you can push items into the array inside a for loop in the following way:

```
{% for image in site.static_files %}
  {% if image.path contains "assets/images/target-folder" %}
     <!-- Push image into array -->
     {% assign my_array = my_array | push: image %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. I've used your fix to later sort this array and then loop through that. Like this: `{% assign sorted_my_array = my_array | reverse %}`.

Comment: this works perfectly, BUT jekyll nor liquid has this function listed anywhere in their docs.

Comment: @user3411192 check this: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split

Comment: let me clarify: the `push` function is nowhere to be seen in Jekyll or Shopify docs. It does what it is supposed to do, but it's a secret function.

Comment: @user3411192 Sorry I get it now, look at "Array filters" in Jekyll docs: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/ you can have a look at: *push* *pop* and *shift*.

Comment: there it is! thanks for clarifying. explains why I don't see it in the shopify docs since it's unique to only Jekyll.

Comment: Thank you, this was a lifesaver! I finally figured out how to wrangle Jenkins+Liquid into [sorting the categories case insensitively](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/victor-engmark.gitlab.io/-/merge_requests/54/diffs#d119e06265596c1c6aba78a5bd1b70f1f08e3057_0_8).

Answer (score 4):

Also note that you can do this *without a loop* using [`where`/`where_exp` filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/):

```
  {% assign my_array = site.static_files | 
      where_exp: "item", "item.path contains 'assets/images/target-folder'" %}
```

or:

```
  {% assign target_folder = "assets/images/target-folder" %}
  {% assign my_array = site.static_files | 
      where_exp: "item", "item.path contains target_foler" %}
```

(Although, unlike the accepted answer, this doesn't precisely correspond to the question's *title*, it's still a useful option in the described example.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
{% assign namesArr = '' %}
{% for animal in animals %}
    {% assign namesArr = namesArr | append: animal.name %}
    {% if forloop.last == false %}
       {% assign namesArr = namesArr | append: "," %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign namesArr = namesArr | split: "," %}
```

Now `namesArr` is array, we can check array contains some value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30823063/5638975