# (Liquid) Checking for a variable in an array

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements, shopify, liquid, unless

I’m looking to find if the title of the current collection page exists inside the array of shop.vendors and display a div only if the collection page title does not exist in the array. From the documentation it seems like I should be able to do this but it doesn't work?

```
{%- unless shop.vendors contains collection.title -%}
 <div> display content in here if condition is not met </div>
{%- endunless -%}
```

Comment: That is correct, try to debug the values of the two variables in the condition like `{{shop.vendors}}` and `{{collection.title}}`

Comment: @FabioFilippi Just tried to debug and the output was as follows `<div>Fairfax &amp; FavourHancock ScotlandHolland CooperOliami Test</div> <div>Fairfax &amp; Favour</div>` The first div is shop.vendors and the second div is collection.title, so it seems like each object is correct but the unless statement still isn't working?

Comment: your code is correct, but I think you misread about unless. it show when it false. but it in your case it is true, because collection title exits into shop.vendors

Comment: Are you sure? In the docs it says show this element unless condition is met?

Comment: For example I have tried to brute force it by doing `unless shop.vendors contains "Fairfax & Favour"` which worked as I expected, but I need it to work for every page

Comment: It work because there is difference between & and &amp;

Comment: Take a look here for more information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822160/does-liquid-have-a-does-not-contain-or-not-in-array-operator

Comment: unless works only when the condition is falsy, and in your case it become true.

Answer (score 1):

So I've found out why this wasn't working, for anyone else who comes across this

`shop.vendors` renders an ampersand as `&amp` rather than `&`, while `collection.title` renders it as `&`. Therefore, if you try to compare the names it won't work.

The solution is doing `| escape` to **only** `shop.vendors` so they're formatted the same, then the comparison will work. I also did `| remove` to get rid of the ampersand entirely as it's not strictly needed in the name comparison **in my case.**

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite your code as:

```
{% for vendor in shop.vendors %}
  {% if vendor == collection.title %}
     <div> display content in here if condition is not met </div>    
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm not looking to have multiple iterations of the same object though

Comment: Ok then it should work:    

**`{% if shop.vendors contains collection.title %}
   <div> display content in here if condition is not met </div>    
{% endif %}`**

Comment: @MandasaTechnologies, want to show the div with content when title is not into vendors list, okay?

Comment: **`{% if shop.vendors contains collection.title %} {% else %}<div> display content in here if condition is not met </div>{% endif %}`**

Use this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).